# Sum / Combine values from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How would one combine values from multidimensional arrays?

Array1

```
Array
(
    [Amie] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amie
            [1] => 12
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 3.3%
            [4] => 0.0
            [5] => 83.2
            [6] => 4.9
            [7] => 772.4
            [8] => 64.4
            [9] => 0.0
            [10] => 0.0
            [11] => 0.0
            [12] => 0.0
            [13] => 0.0
            [14] => 0.0%
            [15] => 7
            [16] => 5
            [17] => 58.3%
            [18] => 41.7%
        )
)
```

Array2

```
Array
(
    [Amie] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amie
            [1] => 16
            [3] => 13.1%
            [4] => 0.0
            [5] => 129.0
            [6] => 9.2
            [7] => 1692.4
            [8] => 120.2
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 0.0
            [11] => 0
            [12] => 0.0
            [13] => 0.0
            [14] => 0.0%
            [15] => 8
            [16] => 6
            [17] => 57.1%
            [18] => 42.9%
      )
)
```

Final array should combine all values so end result would look like this:

```
[Amie] => Array
            (
                [0] => Amie
                [1] => 28
                [2] => 5
                [3] => 16.4%
                [4] => 0.0
                [5] => 212.
                [6] => etc.
```

Tried preserving one array as original, then merging both arrays and looking for values which needed to be updated. I have also tried creating this array from scratch so something like:

```
$finalArray = array_map(function () {
                                return array_sum(func_get_args());
                            },  array_splice($processedReport1, 1), 
                                array_splice($processedReport2, 1));
```

or using foreach and nested foreach loops and all methods give me either nothing or something weird :O

Thanks for help.

Comment: are the keys always the same between the arrays? then `foreach($arr1 as $key => $value) { $arr1[$key] += $arr2[$key] }`

Comment: Whats up with the `%` signs? I assume those are strings how do you want to handle them?

Comment: are you making sure to skip the first element of the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to loop through each entry manually, check to see if it has a percentage sign or not, trim if necessary and then sum the arrays. Something like this:

```
function sum_arrays (array $arr1, array $arr2)
{
    $sum = array();
    foreach ($arr1 as $key => $val)
    {
        // First key is string, skip
        if ($key == 0) continue;

        // Check for percentage sign
        $p = false;
        if (strpos($val, '%'))
        {
            $p = true;
        }

        $sum[$key] = trim($val, '%');
        if (isset($arr2[$key]))
        {
            $sum[$key] += trim($arr2[$key], '%');
        }

        if ($p)
        {
            $sum[$key] .= '%';
        }
    }
    return $sum;
}

$sum = sum_arrays($array1, $array2);
```

**NB:** I've not tested this solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the following, I've merged the keys of the arrays, and checked against the existence of the every key in the union array of the both arrays and acted appropriately; i.e: the values are ultimately converted to `float`s and in the case of string percentages, the numeric part is firstly extracted.

Note the implicit `array_unique` gets applied in the implementation of the `array_merge` as well, hence the obtaining of a union.

```
<?php
function combine_arrays_customized($a1, $a2) {
    $keys = array_merge(array_keys($a1), array_keys($a2));
    $combinedArr = array(0=>$a1[0]);
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        if($key == 0)
            continue;

        $val1 = $val2 = 0;
        $isPercentage = false;
        if(isset($a1[$key])) {
            $v = $a1[$key];
            if(is_string($v) && preg_match('~\d+\.?\d*%$~', $v)) {
                $isPercentage = true;
                $val1 = (float)substr($v, 0, -1);
            }
            else $val1 = (float)$v;
        }
        if(isset($a2[$key])) {
            $v = $a2[$key];
            if(is_string($v) && preg_match('~\d+\.?\d*%$~', $v)) {
                $isPercentage = true;
                $val2 = (float)substr($v, 0, -1);
            }
            else $val2 = (float)$v;
        }
        if($isPercentage)
            $combinedArr[$key] = ($val1 + $val2) . '%';
        else $combinedArr[$key] = ($val1 + $val2);
    }
    return $combinedArr;
}

// test
$a1 = array(0 => 'Amie', 1 => '12', 2 => '5', 3 => '3.3%', 4 => '0.0', 5 => '83.2', 6 => '4.9', 7 => '772.4', 8 => '64.4', 9 => '0.0', 10 => '0.0', 11 => '0.0', 12 => '0.0', 13 => '0.0', 14 => '0.0%', 15 => '7', 16 => '5', 17 => '58.3%', 18 => '41.7%');
$a2 = array( 0 => 'Amie', 1 => '16', 3 => '13.1%', 4 => '0.0', 5 => '129.0', 6 => '9.2', 7 => '1692.4', 8 => '120.2', 9 => '0', 10 => '0.0', 11 => '0', 12 => '0.0', 13 => '0.0', 14 => '0.0%', 15 => '8', 16 => '6', 17 => '57.1%', 18 => '42.9%' );

echo "<pre>";
var_dump(combine_arrays_customized($a1, $a2));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```